# Solve $xa+yb=c$ for $x, y \in \mathbb{C}$ and $a,b,c\in\mathbb{C}^2$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $a=\pmatrix{1\\1}, b=\pmatrix{1\\2}, c=\pmatrix{2\\1}$. Solve $xa + yb = c$ for $x, y \in \mathbb{C}$.

Does this mean I do 
$$1x+1y=2$$
$$1x+2y=1$$
and would be the final answer?

Comment: For some reason you have switched from $1x+1y=2$ to $1x+2y=1$.  Why?

Comment: It's just basic algebra. If $xa+yb=c$, then $yb=c-xa$, then $y=\dfrac{c-xa}{b}$. So you have a straight line assuming b isn't zero.

Comment: I have changed the tag of Linear Algebra to Algebra-Precalculus. I don't see how this applies to Linear Algebra given the little information.

Comment: Its a matrix. That is why.

Comment: It is linear algebra but I dont know how to put it in matrix form form in the post I put

Comment: @KjX: I assume that the way I've rewritten your question is what you intended?

Comment: *and would be the final answer?* No. The answer would be the set of solutions. Here, there is exactly one solution (x,y) and your task is to compute it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Zev's edit is correct, then your equations
$$1x+1y=2$$
$$1x+2y=1$$
are correct.  To complete the problem, you need to find the values of $x$ and $y$ that make both of those equations true at the same time.

> Hint: Subtract the first equation from the second equation.

Comment: Someone is reading meta these days :)

Answer (score 0):

$$1x+1y=2\cdots\cdots(1)$$
$$1x+2y=1\cdots\cdots(2)$$

Multiply (1) by -1
$$-1x-1y=-2 $$ 
Adding above and (2),

$$1x+2y -1x-1y=1-2$$
$$y=-1$$
Put it in (1)
$$1x+1y=2$$
$$1x-1=2$$
$$x=3$$
Solution Set = (3,-1)

Verify this by putting in the 2 equations.